# Dropbox API unable to upload onto user personal Dropbox?

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile, dropbox

I've succeeded onto transferring files onto my Dropbox account.
But when i share my app for testing with other members of the project, they can't transfer the files on their own Dropbox account.

And when they test the functionality, it transfers automatically onto my account.

Is there something I'm missing out here?

I know that i don't need to add manually users, they can automatically transfer the files they want.

Here's a snip of the method i used :

```
 private void UploadToDropboxFromPath(String uploadPathFrom, String uploadPathTo) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload file ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    final String uploadPathF = uploadPathFrom;
    final String uploadPathT = uploadPathTo;
    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            File tmpFile = null;
            try {
                tmpFile = new File(uploadPathF);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(tmpFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                dropboxAPI.putFileOverwrite(uploadPathT, fis, tmpFile.length(), null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File successfully uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    th.start();
}
```

Comment: How are you constructing the `dropboxAPI` object?

Comment: Does the class contain your dropbox identification and credentials?

Comment: Here's the code for the DropBox API

http://pastebin.com/N78Lyusv

Comment: You're explicitly setting an access token. Note that access tokens are user-specific, so any particular access token only applies to a particular account, in this case, yours. In order to let users connect to their own accounts, you need to implement the OAuth app authorization flow as shown here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/android